# PHP mongo update failes. "Invalid modifier specified: $push"

Tags: php, mongodb

i'm trying to update an inner array within a mongo document:

```
   $find = array('_id'   => new mongoId($qId));
   $push = array('$push' => array('questions', ['q' => $question, 'a' => $answers] ) );
   $this->db->questionaires->update( $find, $push );
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid modifier specified: $push
```

My collection is structured like this:

```
> db.questionaires.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e7c1fea7312a9958601a85"),
    "title" : "ff",
    "respondantgroup" : "579dca85a7b294c3f030fb8d",
    "responsible" : "579dc862a7b294c3f030fb8c",
    "questions" : [
        {
            "q" : "",
            "a" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you manage to solve this?